# Force ephemeral port binding in docker-compose

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I'm trying to use kafka-docker: https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker. Docker sets a new port for the kafka brokers every single time I start up the service again. Meaning, the `32781`, `32782`, and `32783` changes every time.

```
$ docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                NAMES
c9e2188366cb        wurstmeister/zookeeper   "/bin/sh -c '/usr/sb…"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        22/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp   kafka-docker_zookeeper_1
d3db1c6b39aa        kafka-docker_kafka       "start-kafka.sh"         5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:32781->9092/tcp                              kafka-docker_kafka_3
3ea8951fef31        kafka-docker_kafka       "start-kafka.sh"         5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:32782->9092/tcp                              kafka-docker_kafka_2
6bf090978b05        kafka-docker_kafka       "start-kafka.sh"         5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:32783->9092/tcp                              kafka-docker_kafka_1
```

I understand why that needs to happen (thanks to this awesome wiki: https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker/wiki/Connectivity).

However, is there a way to hack it so that the ephemeral ports that docker compose chooses starts at the same number? For example, if it ALWAYS started with `32781`, my life would be a lot easier.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you specify a range of port for kafka container, for example, 32781-32790, it will assign port from the range. I can't guarantee it always will start with `32781`, as I didn't find any confirmation regarding it in the documentation, but in my past experience it always starts with the first port in the port range.

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "32781-32790:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 192.168.99.100
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: That only controls that one container, though, not the whole cluster

Comment: @MinhTrangVy If it is satisfactory, please mark the answer as correct :)